# Веб-страница, добавленная на экран "Домой", открывается в Safari

Tags: ios, safari

Необходимо избавить страницу от лишних элементов мобильного браузера, чтобы получилось подобие веб-приложения. Добавляю необходимую страницу "На экран «Домой»", иконка на главном экране появляется, но при нажатии на неё страница открывается в браузере Safari. В чём может быть проблема? P.S.: Пробовал с другими сайтами/страницами, некоторые открываются как отдельные приложения, а некоторые, опять же, в Safari..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Необходимо было добавить метатег

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```